# Azure error when redeploying to different region

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I recently did a deployment to WestEurope by mistake, I deleted the resources and thought I could redeploy to UKSouth, however whenever I try to redeploy I get the error below:

```
 - At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)
   - {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidDeploymentLocation",
    "message": "Invalid deployment location 'uk south'. The deployment already exists in location 'westeurope'."
  }
} (Code:Conflict)
CorrelationId: 8c2a4cd6-4409-46c3-9b7c-544134f0f942
```

The master template calls several nested templates and I'm having trouble trying to identify where the issue lies. I have checked and there's no soft delete enabled anywhere and also the resources have definitely been deleted from Azure.

Help..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using different unique name for resource group or post the deployment template here

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Thanks for that, I'll upload the template file, but there are also several nested templates, could you need to see those too?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni template = https://pastebin.com/embed_js/ctQ77p6v

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not Sure If this is resolved but here is what i did.

1. Go Azure Portal ->Subscription
2. On Left Pane under settings click on Deployments
3. Find the deployment which was done earlier and delete it manually

This should fix your problem.